# How to disable options on select onchange event in mobile browsers in multiselect

Tags: javascript, dom

I need have a multiple select tag and disable some selections when the onchange event fires as the possible amount of selections are limited.

The basic code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectionChange(selection) {
        selection.options[0].disabled = true;
    }
</script>
<select multiple="multiple" onchange="selectionChange(this)">
    <option>Option #1</option>
    <option>Option #2</option>
    <option>Option #3</option>
    <option>Option #4</option>
    <option>Option #5</option>
</select>
```

As you can see nothing special and in desktop browsers works like a charm. The problem is in the mobile browsers.

In Android for example the onchange does not fire until you press OK.
[image]

Now the weird thing is that in iOS Safari, when I use an `alret()` then the alert will fire, but the selection item will remain enabled until I press "Done" and open the select again. However in Android, the alert will not fire until you press OK.

I've spent days looking for a solution here and I am starting to think this can't be done in mobile browsers, but I have not found any reference to this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something similar to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectionClicked(selection) {
        // Check if any option was selected
        if(selection.value) {
            selection.options[0].disabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>
<select multiple="multiple" onclick="selectionClicked(this)">
    <option>Option #1</option>
    <option>Option #2</option>
    <option>Option #3</option>
    <option>Option #4</option>
    <option>Option #5</option>
</select>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectionClicked(selection) {
        // Check if any option was selected
        for(var i=0; i<selection.options.length; i++) {
            if(selection.options[i].selected) {
                selection.options[0].disabled = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: No these function act the same as my original function, they do change the option to disabled, but only when the selection is finished and not while the selection is opened, with is what I need